# Cannot find ldl lnsl lpthread lrt when buildling?

Tags: linux, qnx, data-distribution-service, qcc

I am trying to build the RTI perftest in an i86 QNX architecture. When I try to build the makefile that I generated, I get the following:

```html
Checking directory obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release
Checking directory ../bin/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release
qcc -V4.7.3,gcc_ntox86 -Y_cpp -lang-c++ -m64 -Wall -o ../bin/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/perftest_cpp obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/test.o obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/testPlugin.o obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/testSupport.o obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/Property.o obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/RTIDDSImpl.o obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/perftest_cpp.o -L/opt/RTI/ndds.5.1.0/lib/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3 -lnddscppz -lnddscz -lnddscorez -lm -lsocket  -lpthread -lnsl -lrt -L/usr/lib/nptl
/opt/qnx/6.6.0/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0-ld: cannot find -lpthread
/opt/qnx/6.6.0/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0-ld: cannot find -lnsl
/opt/qnx/6.6.0/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0-ld: cannot find -lrt
cc: /opt/qnx/6.6.0/host/linux/x86/usr/bin/i486-pc-nto-qnx6.6.0-ld error 1
make: *** [../bin/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/perftest_cpp] Error 1
```

I am not to familiar with QNX and its libraries, but when I remove those flags I get a ton of errors. Any tips on how to build the perftest for QNX or dealing with this error would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `makefile` has the following build line which resolves all symbols and results in a running executable:

```
qcc -o ../bin/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/perftest_cpp 
  obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/test.o 
  obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/testPlugin.o 
  obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/testSupport.o 
  obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/RTIDDSImpl.o 
  obj/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3/Release/perftest_cpp.o
  -L/opt/RTI/rti_connext_dds-5.2.3/lib/i86QNX6.6qcc_cpp4.7.3
  -lnddscppz -lnddscz -lnddscorez -lm -lsocket
  -V4.7.3,gcc_ntox86 -Y_cpp -lang-c++ -Wall
```

Note that it has none of the libraries that you mention.